# Does we need to hold wake lock programmatically for work manager or work manager do it by itself?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am new to work manager and I want to know that if we use OneTimeWorkManager so does we need to hold wake lock programmatically or work manager did it by itself. Please guide me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WorkManager does not need wake lock to work.

Always works in background without wake lock

Answer (score 1):

Using WorkManager adds the Wakelock permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml` as the library will use it as needed.

You can use the [Background Task Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/task#inspect-jobs-alarms-wakelocks) to see the active wakelocks.

Please refer to [WorkManager's source code](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/work/work-runtime/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) for additional information.